# ASP.net Gridview Row Deletion

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 6.   I have a gridview displaying orders from a database.  However, I need a user to be able to click a row and be taken to another page for editing that row after a dialog box confirmation.

This is what I have:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridOrders" runat="server" Height="184px" Width="1359px"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    AllowSorting="true" >
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16pt" BackColor="#cc0000" ForeColor="Black"         />
    <RowStyle Font-Size="12pt" BackColor="#afadad" ForeColor="White"/>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#afadad" ForeColor="White" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="" SelectText="CANCEL ORDER" ShowSelectButton="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White"   />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
```

How do I make the row selection to another page happen with a dialog that asks user if they are sure?

Answer (score 0):

> Change your aspx page with the below code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridOrders" runat="server" Height="184px" Width="1359px" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowSorting="True">
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16pt" BackColor="#cc0000" ForeColor="Black" />
            <RowStyle Font-Size="12pt" BackColor="#afadad" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#afadad" ForeColor="White" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancelOrder" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to redirect?')" OnClick="lnkCancelOrder_Click" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("OrderID") %>' CommandName="Select" Text="CANCEL ORDER"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

> Write the c# code as follows
>   You can redirect to another page and pass the orderID as QueryString, and retrieve the complete order information by orderID and show that in an edit mode form

```
protected void lnkCancelOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        string orderID = lnk.CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx?orderId="+orderID);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write under the `<asp:TemplateField>` of Gridview as

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="anchrTag" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Your edit page url" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are u sure to leave this page and want to go for edit?');">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```